# Test class for trigger afterUpdate executes only once?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have a trigger on Account object as :

**AccountTrigger.trigger:**

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert, after update, before insert, 
before update) {
    TrgrMgr.execute(AccountTriggerHandler.class);
}
```

All the triggers are routed to this TrgrMgr class:

**TrgrMgr.cls**:

```
    public with sharing class TrgrMgr {
    public interface TrgrHandlerInterface {
        void beforeInsertEvent(List<sObject> newData);
        void afterInsertEvent(List<sObject> newData, Map<ID, sObject> newDataMap);
    }             

    public abstract class TriggerHandlerCls implements TrgrHandlerInterface {
       public virtual void beforeInsertEvent(List<sObject> newData) {}
       public virtual void afterInsertEvent(List < sObject > newData, Map < ID, sObject > newDataMap) {}
       public virtual void afterUpdateEvent(List < sObject > newData, Map < ID, sObject > newDataMap, Map < ID, sObject > oldDataMap) {}

       private void execute(
           Boolean isBefore, Boolean isAfter, Boolean isInsert, Boolean isUpdate, Boolean isDelete,
           List < SObject > oldData, List < SObject > newData, Map < ID, SObject > oldDataMap, Map < ID, SObject > newDataMap) {
             if(isBefore) {
                if (isInsert) { 
                    beforeInsertEvent(newData);
                }

            }
            else {
                if (isInsert) {
                    afterInsertEvent(newData, newDataMap); 
                }
                if (isUpdate) {
                    afterUpdateEvent(newData, newDataMap, oldDataMap); 
                }
            }
       }
   }

    public static void execute(Type typeParam) {
        Object obj = typeParam.newInstance();
        if (obj instanceof TriggerHandlerCls) {
            execute((TriggerHandlerCls) obj);
        }
        else {            
            system.debug('Error occured');
        }        
    }

    public static void execute(TriggerHandlerCls handlerParam) {
        handlerParam.execute(
            Trigger.isBefore, 
            Trigger.isAfter, 
            Trigger.isInsert, 
            Trigger.isUpdate, 
            Trigger.isDelete,
            Trigger.old, 
            Trigger.new, 
            Trigger.oldMap,
            Trigger.newMap);
    }
}
```

Here is my AccountTriggerHandler class

**AccountTriggerHandler.cls:**

```
    public with sharing class AccountTriggerHandler extends TrgrMgr.TriggerHandlerCls  { 

        public override void afterUpdateEvent(List < sObject > newData, Map < ID, SObject > newDataMap, Map < ID, SObject > oldDataMap) {
            system.debug('+++ entered the afterUpdateEvent method in trigger Account trigger handler and the value is '+ Util.onAfterUpdateAccTrigger);
            if (Util.onAfterUpdateAccTrigger == true) { 
                Util.onAfterUpdateAccTrigger = false;
                afterUpdate((Map < Id, Account > ) newDataMap, (Map < Id, Account > ) oldDataMap);
            }

        }
    private void afterUpdate(Map < Id, Account > newAccountMap, Map < Id, Account > oldAccountMap) {
        System.debug('Entered the afterUpdate for Account Update');
    }


    }
```

And here is my Test class for AccountTriggerHandler:

**AccountTriggerHandlerTest.cls**:

```
@isTest
public with sharing class AccountTriggerHandlerTest {

    private static Account objAccount = null;

    static testMethod void Test_afterUpdate(){
        objAccount = TestHandler.CreateAccount();
        insert objAccount;
        objAccount.Name = 'First Update';
        update objAccount;
        objAccount.Name = 'Second Update';           
        update objAccount;
        objAccount.Name = 'Third Update';            
        update objAccount;
    }
}
```

When I run my test class, I see that afterUpdate method in AccountTriggerHandler class runs only once where as my test class is updating the account three times..

What mistake am I doing here? Is it because I am doing all the updates on sames Account object??

Thanks in Advance..

Hope the question is clear :)

Comment: how do u know the trigger handler is running only once ? i wld suggest to add some debug statements and check the debug logs

Comment: The debug statement in afterUpdate method is executed only once..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, nice to see a trigger pattern posted;

secondly, you are using in your Util class some sort of recursive trigger control hence method `afterUpdate(...)` will only be called once

```
if (Util.onAfterUpdateAccTrigger == true) { 
    Util.onAfterUpdateAccTrigger = false;
    afterUpdate((Map < Id, Account > ) newDataMap, (Map < Id, Account > ) oldDataMap);
 }
```

Normally, when doing multiple DML operations in a testmethod, in order to simulate real user activity, you should call some `resetAll()` method on your Trigger control class (`Util`) to allow triggers to re-execute - that is, simulating what a real user would see if they were clicking Save, waiting for a response, updating a field, and clicking save again

Such `resetAll()` method might look like this

```
public static resetAll() {
    onAfterUpdateAccTrigger = true;
    onAfterUpdateOppoTrigger = true;
    ....
}
```

Comment: We developed this framework from this link https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices      Can you give some clue on how the reset method in Util class should be.. For now, I can create a method to reset this particular variable.. But in general What should go in the reset method?

Comment: i updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You are using static variable "`Util.onAfterUpdateAccTrigger`" to avoid multiple execution of trigger.

```
if (Util.onAfterUpdateAccTrigger == true) { 
                Util.onAfterUpdateAccTrigger = false;
                afterUpdate((Map < Id, Account > ) newDataMap, 
                 (Map < Id, Account > ) oldDataMap);
                }
```

`onAfterUpdateAccTrigger` is static variable and you are trying to update account in same context thats why its not executed more than once.

Comment: you are too fast for me :-)

Comment: :) - just once..

Comment: @JitendraZaa Thanks for your time and now i understood the problem.